# How to use Control.Triggers?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
<ItemsControl Name="workingCardsPanel">
    <ItemsControl.Triggers>
        <Trigger SourceName="workingCardsPanel" Property="HasItems" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="workingCardsPanel" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter TargetName="workingCardsPanel" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF828790"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ItemsControl.Triggers>
    <ItemsControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <ListBoxItem><TextBlock Text="Hello world!"/></ListBoxItem>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

When the ItemsControl has items, I want to set its `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` to corresponding values as demonstrated above.

However the code is not compilable.

I have already managed it when I move the setters to `Style.Triggers`. I just want to know whether `ItemsControl.Triggers` can do it. Or if it cannot, what does ItemsControl.Triggers used for?

One more question.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF828790"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ItemsControl.Triggers>
```

I'm wonder if it is possible that all properties(HasItems, BorderThickness, and BorderBrush) refer to ones of the control without its name. (as the ItemsControl does not have a name now.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may answer my own question.

After searching a lot, to my surprise, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers) explains the usage of FrameworkElement.Triggers.

In a word, only `EventTrigger` can be added to FrameworkElement.Triggers.